# Python function prints None

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have the following exercise:

> The parameter weekday is True if it is
>   a weekday, and the parameter vacation
>   is True if we are on vacation. We
>   sleep in if it is not a weekday or
>   we're on vacation. Return True if we
>   sleep in.

Here's what I've done, but the second print function only prints `'None'`.

```
def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
    if(not weekday or vacation):
        return True

print(sleep_in(False, False))
print(sleep_in(True, False))
print(sleep_in(False, True))
```

Output:

```
True
None
True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions in python return `None` unless explicitly instructed to do otherwise.

In your function above, you don't take into account the case in which weekday is `True`. The interpreter reaches the end of the function without reading a return statement (since the condition predecing yours evaluates to `False`), and returns `None`.

**Edit**:

```
def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
    return (not weekday or vacation)
```

There you go =)

Comment: you don't need brackets there

Comment: @SilentGhost: The parens aren't needed, yes, but they arguably add clarity.

Comment: @delnan I think it's good practice to enclose this kind of comparison logic in parenthesis, even if precedence rules make it unnecessary.