# Python Return is not escaping from for loops

Tags: python, recursion

Here is my code for this problem:

```
def nfsmaccepts(current, edges, accepting, visited):
    print ('iteration', current, ''.join([i[1] for i in visited]))
    if current in accepting:
        print ('accepted')
        return ''.join([i[1] for i in visited])
    else:
        for edge in edges:
            if edge not in visited and current == edge[0]:
                print (edge, ' matched')
                visited.append(edge)
                for i in edges[edge]:
                    if nfsmaccepts(i, edges, accepting, visited) is not None:
                        print (edge, i, ' chosen')
                        return nfsmaccepts(i, edges, accepting, visited)
                    else:
                        visited = visited[:-1]
```

and here are the results:

```
print(nfsmaccepts(1, edges, accepting, []))
iteration 1
(1, 'a') matched
iteration 2 a
(2, 'a') matched
iteration 2 aa
iteration 3 a
(3, 'b') matched
iteration 4 ab
(4, 'c') matched
iteration 5 abc
accepted
(4, 'c') 5 chosen
iteration 5 abc
accepted
(3, 'b') 4 chosen
iteration 4 abc
None
```

I cannot figure out why the program continues to run through for loops and returns None when clearly a terminal call of the recursive function has been reached. Please help!

Comment: I can clearly see a branch which does not have `return` at the end. That is when the `None` is returned.

Comment: Please do not use the "homework" tag on new questions; it's deprecated and in the process of being removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python function prints None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961099/python-function-prints-none)

Answer (score 1):

Your 'accepted' state occurs when you call your function from the `if` statement:

```
if nfsmaccepts(i, edges, accepting, visited) is not None
```

which then continues to print `(4, 'c') 5 chosen`. The previous iteration did the same, so you call it *again* from iteration 4, printing `(3, 'b') 4 chosen` as well.

Perhaps you meant to call that function only once there and store the result before testing and returning?

```
accepts = nfsmaccepts(i, edges, accepting, visited)
if accepts is not None:
    print (edge, i, ' chosen')
    return accepts
```

Comment: success, thank you! I wasn't happy with the two recursive calls in the same branch but couldn't figure a way around it. That's perfect, thanks