# Showing None while printing the output

Tags: python

I have written the following program for demonstration of list of class objects. It take name and score as input for three objects and then it gets stored into a list and at last the program displays all the information i.e. the name and score associated with the object.

```
class Info:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def display(self):
        print(f"Name :- {self.name}, Score :- {self.score}")


game_info = []
for i in range(3):
    n = input("Enter Your Name :- ")
    s = int(input("Enter Your Score :- "))
    game_info.append(Info(n, s))
    print()

for i in range(3):
    print(game_info[i].display())
    print()
```

**Output :-**

```
Enter Your Name :- a 
Enter Your Score :- 1

Enter Your Name :- b 
Enter Your Score :- 2

Enter Your Name :- c 
Enter Your Score :- 3

Name :- a, Score :- 1 
None

Name :- b, Score :- 2 
None

Name :- c, Score :- 3 
None
```

The output is showing `None` every time I try to print the values. So what should I do to remove it from the program output?

Comment: Change `print(game_info[i].display())` to just `game_info[i].display()`. The `display()` method prints the result you want but does not have a `return` value so returns `None`. That means that `print(game_info[i].display())` then becomes `print(None)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function prints None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961099/python-function-prints-none)

Answer (score 3):

`display` function does not return anything. So it default `None`.
So,

```
print(f"Name :- {self.name}, Score :- {self.score}")
```

Print your expected output. But this proints `None`.

```
print(game_info[i].display())
```

You can change `display` function,

```
return f"Name :- {self.name}, Score :- {self.score}".
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As roganjosh pointed out, I was not clear enough in my description. Taking out the print() function from game_info[i].display() in the last for loop will fix the issue.

```
class Info:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def display(self):
        print(f"Name :- {self.name}, Score :- {self.score}")


game_info = []
for i in range(3):
    n = input("Enter Your Name :- ")
    s = int(input("Enter Your Score :- "))
    game_info.append(Info(n, s))
    print()

for i in range(3):
    game_info[i].display()
    print()
```

Output:

```
Enter Your Name :- Bob
Enter Your Score :- 1

Enter Your Name :- Jane
Enter Your Score :- 2

Enter Your Name :- Sally
Enter Your Score :- 3

Name :- Bob, Score :- 1

Name :- Jane, Score :- 2

Name :- Sally, Score :- 3
```

Comment: Added my output. As you can see, you only need to remove the print statement around the game_info[i].display() function to get the desired output

Comment: also: indentation seems to be off, please format your answer code block

Answer (score 1):

Use return in function

```
return("Name :- {}, Score :- {}".format(self.name,self.score))
```

because `game_info[i].display()` prints return value